# Parse last three numbers from .txt

Tags: python

i would like to read from a .txt file, which contains the numbers:

```
0 0 0 -5.0 0.0 0.0
1 1 0 -5.0 0.0 5.0
2 2 0 0.0 0.0 -5.0
3 3 0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4 4 0 5.0 0.0 -5.0
5 5 0 5.0 0.0 5.0
```

I only need the last three numbers of each line. They represend x,y and z values. Furthermore I want 
 to store these coordinates to a Matrix, so that I can use the Matrix containing coordinates 
of points.  I hope you can help me, cause I'm new to this and I didn't find help in other questions

Joe

Comment: If you have attempted to solve this on your own, please include the code you have and describe the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file, iterate over lines, split each line by space, take last 3 elements using [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) and cast the values to float:

```
data = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(map(float, line.split()[-3:]))

print data
```

prints:

```
[[-5.0, 0.0, 0.0],  
 [-5.0, 0.0, 5.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, -5.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [5.0, 0.0, -5.0], 
 [5.0, 0.0, 5.0]]
```